# jquery datepair plugin is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-datepair.

I want to use the datepair example in a MVC app but I'm getting javascript errors.

The script throws the error:  'undefined is not a function'

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code.

View:

```
<p id="basicExample">
    <input type="text" class="date start" />
    <input type="text" class="time start" /> to
    <input type="text" class="time end" />
    <input type="text" class="date end" />`enter code here`
</p>
```

Script:

```
$(function () {
    $('#basicExample .time').timepicker({
        'showDuration': true,
        'timeFormat': 'g:ia'
    });

    $('#basicExample .date').datepicker({
        'format': 'm/d/yyyy',
        'autoclose': true
    });

    // initialize datepair
    $('#basicExample').datepair();
});
```

Comment: For some reason, my original post removed the script tags. I'm referencing. jquery.datepair.js, jquery-2.1.0.js, jquery-ui-1.10.4.js(this is for the datepicker), jquery.timePicker.js

Comment: check your jquery.js is above from others js. or `$(document).ready(function(){};`

Comment: I believe jquery.js is the latest version.  With that, the timepicker.js does not work correctly.  However, according to https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-datepair documentation, datepair.js can work without timepicker. If I remove the timepicker.js, I still receive that error.

Comment: I mean the order you put your .js files, the jquery always must be the first. for example `<script src="jquery.js"/><script src="other.js"/>`

Comment: and I think the problem comes from `$(function () {` and substitute for `$(document).ready(function(){ //your code here });`

Comment: This is my order: jquery-2.1.0.min.js,jquery-ui.js, jquery.datepair.js,customJS.js.  I've alson changed $(function() to $(document).ready(function(), still no luck.

Comment: I think you missing the bootstrap datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add your datepicker function script in footer and remove below line from function :

```
 $('#basicExample').datepair();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your  `$('#basicExample').datepair();`

with

```
// initialize datepair
var datePairElement = document.getElementById('basicExample');
var datepair = new Datepair(datePairElement);
```

assuming you have added all the required scripts for this.
This should work.